# Reloading the tmux session's bash environment

Tags: bash, tmux

I made a major overhaul to bash and bash config files. Afterwards, I started getting flaky behavior  and warnings when trying to reload bash configs in tmux sessions that were spawned on an older bash configuration. So I did:

`exec -c /bin/bash/env bash`

in one of the sessions. Which helped, but now I'm getting still getting other odd behavior. For example, when I do `clear` I get an error:

`TERM environment variable not set.`

How do I cleanly load my new bash configuration and environment into these old sessions?

Comment: In case you don't find a cleaner solution, you could try installing [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) plugin, loading it into your tmux session, saving, then killing your session, and restoring...?

Comment: Or what about a `tmux synchronize-panes` and then `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Yeah, I do have tmux-resurrect. I try to avoid it, though, as my vim sessions are always a mess and I have to refresh windows individually. Haven't gotten around to perfecting that yet.

Comment: Not familiar with synchronize-panes. I will look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest if you have made major changes to your shell profiles and want them to apply to all existing shells, the best thing to do is restart tmux entirely.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: And to think, I came here to find out how to restart tmux entirely.

Comment: So only solution I could find is just `tmux kill-server`. Then run tmux again.